# Why can't I access the search bar in NEI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

For NEI (Not Enough Items) I've got all the options on the top left, but can't see or access the item list and the search bar down on the bottom.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's a typing tab? The search bar?

Answer (score 0):

### It is because your Minecraft window isn't big enough.

NEI automatically hides/resizes elements as your window size gets smaller in order to ensure that everything else is visible.
*The search bar at the bottom of the screen however.. Is an exception to the rule.*

[Pictures to follow soon]

---

**How do you fix it?**
Try making your Minecraft window taller. (Drag the bottom-right corner downwards, and to the right if needed)
Otherwise, you may want to consider changing your GUI scale.

Comment: "[Pictures to follow soon]" -- apparently "soon" really means "more than 4 and a half years later"